# Regular cardinals and unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If a cardinal $\kappa$ is regular then it cannot be written as a union of fewer than $\kappa$ sets, each of size less than $\kappa$.

This seems to be a very useful characterization.  I have seen a proof or two, but can't grasp all the details... I am horrible with ordinal and cardinal arithmetic.  Could someone please give an elementary (as much as possible) proof of this theorem for me?

Comment: What is your definition of regular cardinals?

Comment: $\kappa$ is a limit ordinal and $cf(\kappa)=\kappa$

Comment: It might be wise to strengthen your cardinal arithmetics first, then. One should not attempt to eat a steak with a silly straw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest proof I can think of is as follows.

> Suppose that $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, let $\lambda < \kappa$ and let $\{ A_\xi : \xi < \lambda \}$  be a family of subsets of $\kappa$ each of cardinality $< \kappa$.  As $\kappa$ is regular, then no $A_\xi$ is cofinal in $\kappa$ (since $|A_\xi| < \kappa = \mathrm{cf} ( \kappa)$), meaning that for each $\xi < \lambda$ there is an $\alpha_\xi < \kappa$ such that $A_\xi \subseteq \alpha_\xi$ — what I really mean here is $\beta < \alpha_\xi$ for all $\beta \in A_\xi$.  Again by the regularity of $\kappa$ the family $\{ \alpha _\xi : \xi < \lambda \}$ cannot be cofinal in $\kappa$, and so there is an $\alpha < \kappa$ such that $\alpha_\xi < \alpha$ for all $\xi < \lambda$.  But then it easily follows that $\bigcup_{\xi < \lambda} A_\xi \subseteq \alpha \subsetneq \kappa$.

There is no cardinal/ordinal arithmetic needed here; all we have used is the definition of cofinality.  If there are particular points that are troubling you, please point them out and I can (try to) elucidate further.

Comment: Ok this is exactly what I was looking for.  I actually tried something very similar, applying the definition twice, but confused myself at the end.  In your first step, I take it you are just assuming the sets A are subsets of kappa, using the cardinality bijection. If only you could see the *other* proof I was trying to understand!

Comment: @DavidL. In my first step I am just taking the usual [von Neumann definition of an ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) (the set of all ordinals strictly less than it) and noting that cardinals are just ordinals of a particular type.  I'm quite glad I don't have to see the _other proof_ you have been pouring over!